# combine two lists of dictionaries of equal length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python v3.10.4.

I have two lists of dictionaries that are the same length typically a few hundred lines long, I need to combine them. These lists they represent security indicators of compromise that need to be enriched and fed to a firewall:

```
uniq = [
    {'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298167'},
    {'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298204'}
]
iocvalue = [
    {'value': '116.30.7.55'}, 
    {'value': '31.215.70.187'}
]
```

I'd like to produce this arrangement:

```
 summary = [{uniq-name:'2022-06-26 14:21:25.298167', 
 value:'116.30.7.55'}]
```

I've tried:

```
 [{[val for val in uniq] + [ val for val in iocvalue]}]
```

as well as several variations of **uniq, **iocvalue, but I couldn't get it working. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union operation between each pair of dictionaries using a list comprehension and `zip()`. The syntax for the union operation depends on the Python version:

### Python 3.9+

```py
[fst | snd for fst, snd in zip(uniq, iocvalue)]
```

### Python <3.9:

```py
[dict(**fst, **snd) for fst, snd in zip(uniq, iocvalue)]
```

(Note that the `dict(**x, **y)` syntax is still supported in Python 3.9+, it's just that using `|` instead is just more concise and readable.)

These output:

```py
[
 {'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298167', 'value': '116.30.7.55'}, 
 {'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298204', 'value': '31.215.70.187'}
]
```

Comment: Functional approach for python 3.9+ which should be slightly faster: `list(map(or_, uniq, iocvalue))` Imports: [`or_()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be usefull.

You need to zip both dict:

```
zipped = zip (uniq,iocvalue)
```

But zipped is now a 'zip object'

To access it, you can do:

```
print (*zipped)
```

Then you get this output:

> ({'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298167'}, {'value': '116.30.7.55'}) ({'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298204'}, {'value': '31.215.70.187'})

Answer (score 0):

`

```
summary = []

for i, j in zip(uniq, iocvalue):

   i.update(j)
   summary.append(i)

# Answer: [{'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298167', 'value': '116.30.7.55'}, {'uniq-name': '2022-06-26 14:21:25.298204', 'value': '31.215.70.187'}]
```

`